# UWP: application wide TextBlock foreground crashes app when set from static resource

Tags: c#, uwp, textblock, foreground, staticresource

I went through a lot of similar questions on SO, in regards to setting the foreground of a TextBlock through a static resource, but for whatever reason my UWP application keeps crashing on me.

I am starting to believe this is a limitation of UWP? Also, no stacktrace is generated from this.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 v.17.2.6

***ThemeColors.xaml***

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyOffWhiteBrush" Color="#eeeeee" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

***TextBlockStyle.xaml***

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MyOffWhiteBrush}" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

***App.xaml***

```
<Application
    x:Class="TestTextBlock.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestTextBlock">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ThemeColors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="TextBlockStyle.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

***MainPage.xaml***

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestTextBlock.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestTextBlock"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="helloworld" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

---

**UPDATE #1:**

If I change `TextBlockStyle.xaml` to this it works.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="_" />
    
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MyOffWhiteBrush}" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I don't understand why I need to declare an empty brush?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behavior may be related to the [Lookup behavior for XAML resource references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-resource-dictionary) and [Forward references within a ResourceDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-resource-dictionary). You need to make sure the referenced resource must appear lexically before the resource reference when you use the resource.

I agree with **@Mark W**, the possible workaround is that you could define the basic resource on top of other resources.

In your scenario, it should be like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ThemeColors.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MyOffWhiteBrush}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. TY!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer for why... In my application, I have a number of styles - separated out into color/brushes, sizes and layouts, and then default styles... for each dictionary that references other dictionaries, I include them at the top.

ColorsAndBrushes does not have any references.

SizesAndLayout does not have any references.

DefaultStyles references the two above.

```
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ColorsAndBrushes.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="SizesAndLayout.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

so for my next layer, "NamedStyles", I have have the following to the top:

```
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ColorsAndBrushes.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="SizesAndLayout.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="DefaultStyles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

I don't know if this will work better for you, but maybe feels a little better than the random empty brush.  And my app.xaml references all of them.  This was build on a older (AnniversaryEdition) UWP SDK, so your mileage may vary.

Good luck!
-Mark